# MySQL Query with Idiorm and Date Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, idiorm

I want to use a chart on some of my data and generate the values based on selected dates (with a date picker). I've stolen most of the stuff on the web and might have only a simple questions.

Here is the Idiorm query:

```
if (isset($_GET['start']) AND isset($_GET['end'])) {

$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];
$data = array();

// Select the results with Idiorm
$results = ORM::for_table('tbl_data')
        ->where_gte('date', $start)
        ->where_lte('date', $end)
        ->order_by_desc('date')
        ->find_array();


// Build a new array with the data
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key]['label'] = $value['date'];
    $data[$key]['value'] = $value['rev'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
}
```

The `$start` and `$end` are from my datepicker and in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. The only thing I don't know how to do is how to change the `->where_gte` statement. As you can see it's querying the db for the field `date`. In my db I have three fields, `year`, `month` and `day`.

Is there a way to combing the three fields `year`, `month` and `day` into one expression i.e. maybe `->where_gte('year'&'month'&'day', $start)`???

I tried searching and searching but maybe have the wrong keywords or to less knowledge.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have three fields in the DB, you need three `where_gte` clauses:

```
...
->where_gte('year', substr($start, 0, 4) // or most suitable date_format
->where_gte('month', substr($start, 5, 2) // or most suitable date_format
...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage date format using MySql `DATE_FORMAT()` Function. E. G.:

```
// Select the results with Idiorm
$results = ORM::for_table('tbl_data')
        ->where_gte('date', "DATE_FORMAT($start, '%Y-%m-%d')")
        ->where_lte('date', "DATE_FORMAT($end, '%Y-%m-%d')")
        ->order_by_desc('date')
        ->find_array();
```

Comment: Thanks - but I don't have a date field in my sql table. What I'm looking for is to create a date based on the the values for year, month and day I do have.